# List<? extends Object> what I can store into it?

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to java and I have the code like this:

```
List<? extends Object> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();
k.add(new Integer(1));
```

I'm getting the error like:

```
Error:(13, 10) java: no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Integer)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object)
```

I have few questions:

1. `List<? extends Object> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();` why in right hand side of the equation doesnt allow me to put `new ArrayList<? extends Object>()` ?
2. `<? extends Object>` means any class extend `Object` right? So in java all class does extend `Object`, so why I'm getting error in line:

`k.add(new Integer(1));`

3. While declaring, java allowed me to give `new ArrayList<Integer>()`, but allowing me to add `Integer` why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though while declaring, java allowed me to give new `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Yes.  However, it also allows you to assign an `ArrayList<String>`.

Since you don't know what the list is supposed to store, you can't add anything (except `null`).

Comment: isn't the `Object` class he uses just a class for generic objects?

Comment: I have asked 3 questions. What do you mean by *Since you don't know what the list is supposed to store*

Comment: @batman: The `?` means any type.  It could be a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>` or any other type, and you have no idea which.  This actually answers all of your questions; it doesn't make sense to _create_ a list of unknown type.  Learn about covariance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, welcome to java's broken generic system. The question mark as a type parameter means "unknown type". `List<T>.add` is declared to accept a parameter of type `T`. So, in your case, it is supposed to be unknown. Because the Integer's type is known, you cannot call it like that.

Why use a question mark as a type parameter at all then? Well, sometimes, the concrete type of the list elements does not matter, you only care about a type boundary.
For example:

```
public void printDoubles(List<? extends Number> l) {
   for(Number n : l) System.out.println(n.doubleValue() * 2);
}
```

Could this be done with just `List<Number>` instead? Well, as it turns out, it cannot, because lists (and containers in general) in java are not covariant on their element types (there is actually a reason for it). It means that `List<Integer>` is not a subclass of `List<Number>`, so, if function above was declared to accept a parameter of type `List<Number>`, it would be fairly useless, because you could not pass a list of integers (or of any other numeric type) to it without casting.

So, to get around this problem, they have invented the question mark. This declaration is actually equivalent to `<T extends Number> public void printDoubles(List<T> l)`, except that it makes it more clear to the reader, that the function specifically does not care about a particular concrete type of the list elements.

Comment: This seems totally correct to me, but why the 2 downvotes?